# $n$-dimensional comparison test

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $x\in \mathbb R^n$ and $\epsilon >0$, I wonder how to determine the constant $C$, independent of the choice of $x$, such that

$$\sum_{k\in \mathbb Z^n}(1+|x+k|)^{-n-\epsilon} \le C \int_{\mathbb R^n} (1+|y|)^{-n-\epsilon} dy.  $$

I believe I can deal with the dimension $1$ case. But for higher dimensions things get really complicated and abstract and I can't determine this $C$.

Answer (score 0):

All of these functions are radial, so go to the $n$ dimensional polar or spherical coordinates

$$dy = r^{n-1}dr d\Omega$$

Where $d\Omega$ holds all of the angular coordinates because it is the surface measure of the unit $n-1$ sphere.In that case the integral becomes

$$\int d\Omega \int_0^\infty \frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r)^{n+\epsilon}}dr$$

The first integral becomes the area of the sphere, which we can denote $\omega_{n-1}$. The other integral can be bounded by

$$\leq \int_0^1 r^{n-1}dr + \int_1^\infty r^{-1-\epsilon}dr = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$

and $\omega_{n-1} \leq 2\sqrt{\pi^n}$

Comment: Thanks, so how do you deal with the lattice sum and how to find C?

Comment: @NoOne WLOG we only have to look values of $x$ on $[0,1]^n$. If you were to imagine sliding around the surface of this function above this patch, the max overapproximation occurs at $0$. This isn't the max overapproximation for the whole function (because the "bottom left" corner as it were gives a minimum in some quadrants) but the max discrepancy between block and the height of the function is $(1+\sqrt{n})^{n+\epsilon}$ by taking the ratios of opposite corners. This is our $C$ because it ensures that the Riemann sum over those patches is always an under approximation.